# Fortran format in Python specifier X

Tags: python, file, formatting

Hello I am trying to use the FortranFormat module to write the output file in a specific format.
In fortran this format is
`'(X,I2,X,I4, 4(3X, F5.1, X, F5.1, X, F5.1, X, F5.1))'`

When I put this format in FortranFormat :

```
first_line = ff.FortranRecordWriter('(X,I2,X,I4, 4(3x, F5.1, X, F5.1, X, F5.1, X, F5.1))')
```

the following error is raised:

```
InvalidFormat: Token 
  Token: type=ED2,  value=X has invalid neighbouring token
```

When I exclude the `X` specifiers

```
first_line = ff.FortranRecordWriter('(I2,I4, 4(F5.1, F5.1, F5.1, F5.1))')
```

then it works fine, but then I do not write the variables in the exact specified positions.

Comment: I think **all** uses of the `X` specifier must be preceded by an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much @martineau ! When I changed to 'first_line = ff.FortranRecordWriter('(1X,I2,1X,I4, 4(3X, F5.1, 1X, F5.1, 1X, F5.1, 1X, F5.1))')' it worked!

Comment: That's good to hear. It's been many, many years since I've written any Fortran.

Comment: Also myself had made a fortran course at university, but it's a long long time since then. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes - this is correct. Standard Fortran always requires an integer in front of the X edit descriptor, and the format given in the question is incorrect without them.

Comment: @KostasFr: By many years ago, I meant in the neighborhood of 40.